# Blender UV unwrapping non-uniformly

Tags: uv

At first, I was able to uv unwrap the model without a problem. However, I now have been having issues with it. I don't know how it started or what triggered it to start unwrapping in this manner. Here is a screenshot of the issue.

[image]

It is not just the hand that has this issue. When unwrapping other parts that have been unwrapped and not unwrapped the same issue occurs. How would the issue be resolved? I'm using the normal uv unwrapping instead of the smart unwrapping. However, the normal version had no issue until now.

Comment: Did you by any chance added or removed seams between the old unwrap and the wrong one?

Comment: @Nobinberg I'm not aware of doing so. I thought that I would be able to reset the unwrapping on a set of faces simply by using the Unwrap tool.

Comment: ok, because I saw those red edges on your model that looked like markedseams to me, so I thought the problem was the you modified the number of seams. So you wanted to do a new unwrap only on a part of the model?

Comment: Yes, I was manually unwrapping the model. However, for some reason the unwrapping started giving weird results. The markedseams in the picture are unwrapped sections, actually.

Comment: Ok I'm going to try and write an answer, since the comments' length is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to unwrap only a part of the model you have to select the faces first and then unwrap them with whatever method you want, if you select everything it's going to unwrap everything.

I think the main problem here is that when you painted the texture, the UVs where placed in a certain manner and by unwrapping again after you were done painting you basically moved your UVs so the colors you painted before are not corresponding anymore to your model. I've put these two images below to explain better what I mean: I moved two vertices on the UV and the whole front face looks very different, this is basically what I think happened when you did the second unwrap.

[image]
[image]

At this point I see two ways you can solve your problem, either you adjust the UVs yourself by moving, scaling etc. or you keep the UV like that and paint another texture for it (create a new image just to not overwrite the one you have, you never know), maybe by painting directly on your model in Texture Paint mode. I know it is a pain to do something like this all over again (I've been there) but as far as I know these are the quickest options you have.